# Conductor-Dielectric Boundary Conditions

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors, boundary-conditions, dielectric

We have a conductor of resistivity $\rho$ and has a boundary with a dielectric of permittivity $\epsilon$ and we have displacement vector $\vec D$ at an angle $\alpha$ with normal to the boundary and directed from conductor to the dielectric. I need to find the conductor's surface charge density and current density in the vicinity of the boundary.

I have no idea how to approach this setup, but I have a few results that I thought might be useful.

Boundary Conditions

Using $\oint E\cdot dl=0$, I can find that for two seperate media $1,2$:

$$E_{1,\text{tangential}}=E_{2,\text{tangential}}$$

Using $\oint D\cdot ds=0$, I can find that for two seperate media $1,2$:
$$D_{1,\text{normal}}=D_{2,\text{normal}}$$

and we know $\vec D=\epsilon_0\vec E$

Also, we know that $\nabla E=\sigma/\epsilon_0$ or $\nabla D=\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is surface charge density. I thought here that $\sigma=D$ but the answer is $D=\sigma cos\alpha$. I doubt why there is a $\cos\alpha$ term here.

For current density also according to the answer, we are taking perpendicular $\sin \alpha$ term. So Please help why these terms are being added, what's the logic behind it?